# Create silverlight panoramic viewer

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

We want to create a silver light viewer to view panoramic spherical images (png,  jpeg). How to create panoramic viewer in silver light 5 in vs 2010. As google custom street view or as done in three.js

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate control in silverlight to do this, But you can make use of this

[Panomaric view](http://panocube.codeplex.com/)

[360 Image view](http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/08/31/creating-a-360-degree-panorama-in-silverlight/)

Comment: Sajeetharan: Thank you for your suggestions. We are looking for spherical panorama viewer; you refer to cubical and cylindrical